# If condition inside case

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm converting some MySQL 5.0 functions to Oracle 11g.

I need to place an `IF` inside a case but get an error (missing right parenthesis)
this is my code

```
SELECT SUM(
    CASE PTIPO
      WHEN 0 THEN (SELECT IF(A.NT = 0) THEN A.VALOR ELSE 0 END IF FROM DUAL)
      WHEN 1 THEN (SELECT IF(A.NT = 1) THEN A.VALOR ELSE 0 END IF FROM DUAL)
      WHEN 2 THEN (SELECT IF(A.NT = 1) THEN A.VALOR ELSE -A.VALOR END IF FROM DUAL)
    END)
INTO nresp
FROM mov_caja a
JOIN enc_movp b ON a.docid = b.docid
JOIN c_caja c ON a.cajaid = c.cajaid
WHERE c.cajaid
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`IF / ELSE` are used for flow control inside functions and prepared statments, rather than for assembling conditions in single statements.

Really you just need to nest another `CASE` inside using its other syntactic format `CASE WHEN <condition> THEN <value>`:

```
SELECT SUM(
    CASE PTIPO
      WHEN 0 THEN (CASE WHEN (A.NT = 0) THEN A.VALOR ELSE 0 END)
      WHEN 1 THEN (CASE WHEN (A.NT = 1) THEN A.VALOR ELSE 0 END)
      WHEN 2 THEN (CASE WHEN (A.NT = 1) THEN A.VALOR ELSE -A.VALOR END)
    END)
INTO nresp
FROM mov_caja a
JOIN enc_movp b ON a.docid = b.docid
JOIN c_caja c ON a.cajaid = c.cajaid
WHERE c.cajaid
```

Comment: This style worked well for me.  Thanks for the good and simple example and answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can rewrite it as:

```
SELECT SUM(
    CASE 
      WHEN PTIPO = 0 and A.NT  = 0 THEN A.VALOR 
      WHEN PTIPO = 0 and A.NT <> 0 THEN 0
      WHEN PTIPO = 1 and A.NT  = 1 THEN A.VALOR 
      WHEN PTIPO = 1 and A.NT <> 1 THEN 0
      WHEN PTIPO = 2 and A.NT  = 1 THEN A.VALOR 
      WHEN PTIPO = 2 and A.NT <> 1 THEN -A.VALOR 
    END)
INTO nresp
FROM mov_caja a
JOIN enc_movp b ON a.docid = b.docid
JOIN c_caja c ON a.cajaid = c.cajaid
WHERE c.cajaid
```

Comment: De nada, Alejandro. Parece que esta pregunta he tenido mejor aceptación que la [anterior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14504645/inline-if-statement-in-oracle) ... ;)